# Why bipolar neurons in retina transfer information via graded potentials?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, eyes, human-eye, senses

Why should bipolar cells prefer graded potentials to action potentials?

**My attempt**:
I know that graded potentials are better in processing information since stimulus is directly proportional to response generated unlike action potential where the response is always same.

**Reasons**:
But I don't understand its need in bipolar cells , because graded potentials  have already been generated in rods and cones. Also the final message coming out of eye is in the form of action potentials from ganglion cells. If graded potentials were of that importance then why they do stop at bipolar cells and continue as action potentials in the later pathway?

Finally, graded potentials are slower than action potentials so latter should be preferred in places like eyes where response is needed to be quick.

Comment: "where response is needed to be quick" - note that vision (in vertebrates) is actually incredibly slow.

Comment: Relatively it maybe slow but in absolute terms it's still fast. Quick response from rods help a lot in activities like fast car racing, gaming, hunting etc